# css opacity transition not working

Tags: html, css, hover, opacity

For an website I want to show some pictures in a table, but because some of them are Stock Photos, so I need a Source. I want that the source is shown while the user hovers over the picture. So I put the source tag in a class (.PicSource) and gave it { opacity 0; transition all .2s ease-in} and while hovering on the Picture (.ServPic) .ServPic:hover + .PicSource {opacity: 1}.
But it doesn't show the source text and I don't know why. Other hover-Events work fine. I use the same thing for hiding the Caption while hovering and there is everything fine.

So here an Example Code (it should change opacity of .PicSource to 1 but it doesnt, so you may change it manually to see it)

```css
.ServPic {
  width: 350px;
  height: 275px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
}

.PicCapt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
}

.PicSource {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 20%;
  opacity: 0;
  color : #000000;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

.ServPic:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ServPic:hover+.PicCapt {
  opacity: 0;
}

.ServPic:hover+.PicSource {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <img class="ServPic" src="https://cdn.lrb.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Lorem_Ipsum.jpg">
        <a class="PicCapt">CAPTION</a>
        <a class="PicSource">SOURCE.COM</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "+" slector is for direct siblings. Select general siblings by using "~".

See [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1ud3twdo/)

Code:

```
.ServPic:hover ~ .PicSource {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Let me just add some explanation to sibling selectors in css.

For a starter, siblings are elements that are on the exact same level in your html.

An example:

```
<div>
   <p id="sibling1"></p>
   <p id="sibling2"></p>
   <a id="sibling3"></a>
</div>
<p>I am not a sibling of 1, 2 and 3.</p>
```

Sibling 1, 2 and 3 are all on the same level in your markup. The p-tag under your div is on the same level as the div, but not as sibling 1, 2 and 3.

Now the **direct** sibling of sibling1 is sibling2. The direct sibling of Sibling2 is sibling3, but **not** 2, that is important.

The **general** siblings of Sibling1 are sibling2 and sibling3.

Comment: For further explanation about selectors i'd recommend [this article from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) It's important to be able to properly differentiante between their nuances.